# How do I parse UTC time and display the local time in JodaTime java?

Tags: java, jodatime

```
String strDateTime = "2015-08-14 16:25:12"; //From database that was stored in UTC
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);     
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(strDateTime, dateTimeFormatter);
LocalDateTime local = dateTime.toLocalDateTime();
// local = 2015-08-14T16:25:12.000

I want to get the date in my local time zone???
where local = 2015-08-14T11:25:12.000 // 11 VS 16
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Joda, a `LocalDateTime` isn't the *DateTime where you are now*, it's *a DateTime without any time zone information*. From [the docs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html):

> LocalDateTime is an unmodifiable datetime class representing a datetime without a time zone.

By asking for dateTime.toLocalDateTime(), you're just asking for the same DateTime as the original UTC version, but with the UTC information stripped away. Instead, it sounds like you want to convert between time zones; LocalDateTime probably isn't useful to you or your solution.

Use [DateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone)](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toDateTime(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)) to convert between time zones; you can use [DateTimeZone.getDefault](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#getDefault()) to get the system's default time zone, which is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Try this using the ISO date time format:

```
    String startDate = "2013-07-12T18:31:01.000Z";
    DateTime dt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).parseDateTime(startDate);
```

Here you have more information: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTime%28%29

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question. It just strips away the UTC timezone. Still results in wrong answer.